# How to match multiple sites with the same domain with Chrome extension content scripts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Trying to match content scripts to multiple sites with the same domain but different TLDs results in it only matching to one of the sites:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://foo.org/*", "https://foo.com/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
],
```

In this case it's only matching foo.com and not foo.org. Is this behavior documented somewhere, and is there some way to make it match every site in the list?

This also doesn't work:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://foo.org/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
  },
  {
    "matches": ["https://foo.com/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
  }
],
```

It ends up only matching `foo.com`.

Screenshot of the Details dialog:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Those urls aren't the final urls loaded in the browser: a `www.` prefix is added by Google's server.

Comment: If the issue was the www subdomain, neither of the domains would match.  I changed it to a generic domain to make it more clear. I've also added a screenshot of the Details dialog showing that only one of the domains is matched.

Comment: I can confirm the permission warnings, I'm going to test actual matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm the permission warnings get compressed into one domain, which is strange and potentially *very* misleading.

Think `whitehouse.gov` and `whitehouse.com` [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehouse.com), if you're not familiar with the latter], Chrome prefers `.com` for the permission warning. Seems worth a bug report.

However, I can't confirm the actual problem of it *not* being injected. Both forms lead to the content script being injected in my testing.

Comment: Interesting. Coincidentally, yesterday I updated [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-track-me-google/gdbofhhdmcladcmmfjolgndfkpobecpg) that changed added new Google domains to the set of permissions and the update got published without disabling the extension. [This seems intentional](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/0412744604981ba5d11ef68dfa356ed3d509fc21/chrome/common/extensions/permissions/chrome_permission_message_provider.cc#220) ([introduced here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d6a5c78cdf301ec44d0d3a04594e72d5eb6dd4ae%5E%21/)).

Comment: And [`.com` is classified higher than any other domain](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/1ec595593569502139b7c3876828565d4325aa70/extensions/common/permissions/permission_message_util.cc#19).